# Design pattern to handle different inputs working on the similar algorithm

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

So, this is pretty basic question but I thought I will see if someone could give a nice solution to it.

I have two similar implementations which work on different types of inputs and call same service but different APIs on the basis of the input and also perform some basic operations on the basis of the response of the previous call. I am looking for a better/logical/OOO way to represent this in java code.

```
public class C1 {

public O1 M1(I1 input) {

      callServiceXMethodA(input.a(), input.b()....)
      callServiceXMethodB(input.a(), input.b()....)
      callServiceYMethodA(input.a(), input.b()....)
      callServiceYMethodB(input.a(), input.b()....)
      extraStep1();

}

}

public class C2 {

public O2 M2(I2 input) {

     callServiceXMethodA(input.a(), input.b()....)
     callServiceXMethodSTU(input.a(), input.b()....)
     callServiceYMethodPQR(input.a(), input.b()....)
     callServiceYMethodB(input.a(), input.b()....)
     extraStep2();

}

}
```

I do see the a bit of template pattern (with some hierarchy on the input) or the visitor (though I am not too convinced given that there are only two input types).

I was thinking to keep an abstract class to put major chunk and keep abstract methods with whatever needs different values from the concrete implementation and entry point is the concrete class which routes the request with common parameters to the abstract class.

Can someone suggest a way to cleanly do this in OOO way?

Comment: Is `callServiceXMethodA()` overloaded or generic, or does `input.a()` just have the same type in both cases (or compatible types)? My immediate thought is something with generics, but I need something concrete before I can tell.

Comment: Actually they are different APIs most of the times. Sometimes, APIs are same and hence inputs are compatible/similar too.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Well, there are a lot of steps which are same but just because input type is different, they have been duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

By the class and method names i cant tell exactly what you need. What i am thinking is that you can create facades to pack the logic of methods and then maybe you can combine the facades in a way that fits you.

If the methods cant be packed to a logical facade you can create objects and use composition. For example if C1 is your base object and C2 is composed of C1 you can combine the methods to construct a "better" C2 object from C1. And when you call C2 methods you can delegate also to C1.